# ¿cómo detecto si una cuenta fue borrado de Firebase(auth)?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app en android studio el cual tiene inicio de sesión, me gustaría que alguien me explique como detecto que, en caso de borrar una cuenta manualmente de la **consola de Firebase**, cierre sesión al iniciar la app. Si bien en mi `activity main` uso:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null){
        sendToMain();
    }
}
```

Existe otra forma de detectar si el usuario es borrado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacer referencia al mismo nodo donde esta apuntado el usuario en el `DataBase` y con un `eventListener` que chequee si el dato esta, si no esta es que fue borrado. El `currentuser != null` solo va a chequear que si la conexion con el `FirebaseAuth` fue exitosa o no, esto te devuelve el current user que pudo loguearse, que a su vez no chequeea si esta o no en la base de datos, sino que te va a devolver si existe una conexion activa o no.

Comment: Agrego solo un comentario, el getCurrentUser() puede devolver datos cacheados hasta una hora después de eliminado desde la consola. Por eso si anticipas que vas a estar eliminando usuarios via consola la mejor estrategia es la que menciona @Gaston ya que te permite usar el chequeo de reglas de la BD que es inmediato SIEMPRE Y CUANDO tengas las reglas para asegurar que la BD solo sea leida por usuarios autenticados.